# Business Objects - Summary Calculation

Tags: business-objects

I have a report returning teams, case IDs and dates. Each team has multiple cases and each case belongs to only one team. Each case has multiple dates and each date belongs to only one case.

I need to build a summary table that lists all the teams and for each one counts the number of cases for which the latest date was in timescale. For a date to be in timescale it must be within 42 days of the previous date for the same case.

E.g. The two latest dates for Case#1 are 01/08/2021 and 01/09/2021, so this should be counted for the governing team. The two latest dates for Case#2 are 01/07/2021 and 01/09/2021 so this case should NOT be counted for the governing team.

What formula will perform this count?
I can't seem to get anything other than null or MULTIVALUE results.

Answer (score 0):

If you show `team` in your block :

> Updated answer

- start date

```
=If(
  Count(
    [date]
    In([case]; [date])
  )In([case]) <= 1;
  [case start date];
  Previous([date])
)
```

- end date

```
=If(
  IsNull([date]);
  CurrentDate();
  [date]
)
```

- Days since previous update

```
=If(
  [case] = Previous([case])
  And ([date]=Max([date]) In ([case]));
  DaysBetween([start date]; [end date])
)
```

- cases in timescale

```
=Sum(
  If([Days since previous update] <= 42; 1; 0)
  In([team]; [case]; [date])
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm only interested in the final date's timeliness, so I added 'And ([date]=Max([date]) In ([case]))' and that's done the trick. Also I think the '[team]=Previous[team]' is superfluous because if the previous row is a different team then it must also be a different case.

Comment: I have a couple of edge situations to account for though. Some cases only have one date and this needs to be compared against a separate date object (call it 'start') but this is only for cases with exactly one date. The other edge situation is with cases that have no dates at all and for these I need to compare the start date to the current date (i.e. if the current date is far enough from the start date then the case counts as out of timescale). Any ideas for how to account for these?